# Ampersend in this SCSS code mean?

Tags: sass

I have such SCSS code.

```
 .c-notification {
  &__container {
    top: 7px;
    z-index: $z-index-10;
  }
}
```

What exactly does "&__container" is it inclusion or something?
https://sass-lang.com/guide I found nothing like this.

Comment: Look at the documentation of [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ampersand is used to refer to the parent selector. In other words, it kind of prefixes the selector of the parent block to the current selector.

Sass:

```
.c-notification {
  &__container {
    top: 7px;
  }
}
```

Rendered CSS:

```
.c-notification__container {
    top: 7px;
}
```